# Security vulnerabilites in Windows updates from local network

Tags: windows, exploit, operating-systems, windows-10, updates

Windows has offered the ability to download updates from machines in the local network for some time. My gut feeling tells me this would be a great attack vector for Windows security vulnerabilites.

Have there been security vulnerabilites (be that remote code executions, information disclosure or other) in this feature of Windows in the past?

Comment: *"My gut feeling tells me this would be a great attack vector Windows security vulnerabilites."* - please clarify your gut feeling, i.e. what kind of vulnerabilities you would expect here and why?

Answer (score 2):

[The updates are signed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/2019-sha-2-code-signing-support-requirement-for-windows-and-wsus-64d1c82d-31ee-c273-3930-69a4cde8e64f). This means only updates authorized by Microsoft will be installed. If you attempt to substitute your own they will be rejected.

Comment: To be more precise:  only updates signed with Microsoft's key.  It is possible that something has been signed with their key, but not authorized by Microsoft.